# How do you remove the errors from Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am getting warning errors when developing Chrome extensions. Unfortunately, this would be fixed in the next release of a package I am using.

I want to disable the errors as shown in the page below in Developer Mode also. Is there any way to override this error from showing up even in Developer Mode?

PS: The screenshot is from a different extension but the principle is same.

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you solved the issue?

Comment: It was not an issue. I added the screenshots there to demo. What I wanted was to prevent errors from showing up regardless of the extension

Comment: Then why did you accept that answer?

Comment: Did you read OP's comment? They want a general solution of hiding errors. And did you look at the extension's name? You "fixed" [an example of a bad extension](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/tut_debugging/).

Comment: And downvoting bad answers isn't bad sportsmanship. Those two upvotes are probably from someone who upvotes out of courtesy, not because the answer helped them. The accept was also probably done out of courtesy, because it was the only answer. OP already explained it to you, why that wasn't the issue.

Comment: Also questions that turn out to be typos are considered off-topic. If you think this is a typo, then you should have flagged it for closure and not answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function callback)` with capital I

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I found the answer here:

I know that this is an old question, but coming here today I found a new solution and decided to add my two cents.

In the Chrome console there is a gear option on the far right. Clicking on it will reveal a few options.

Make sure that you are showing only logs from top, and that Selected context only is selected.

This will hide all errors from extensions.

[image]

This answer is copied from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/357354/chrome-hide-extension-errors-in-javascript-console)